# NSOperationQueue finish concurrent operations in 1 minute (60 seconds)

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a problem using `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` with `AFNetworking`. 
When I launch a `NSOperation` that connect with a WebService and `MaxConcurrentOperationCount > 1` then 1 minute after receive a timeout.

Instead, if launch the same operation with `MaxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` then the operation finalize correctly 2 minutes after.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.